# How do I interpret this debugger output?

Tags: ruby, debugging, intellij-idea, rubymine

Can anyone tell me how to get nth value, lets say 3rd val (which is 1) in `children[0]` in the following debugger output? I tried `children[0][2]` but didn't work.

```
children = Array (101 elements)
 [0] = Hash (1 element)
  bitstring => Array (100 elements)
   key = {Symbol} bitstring
   value = Array (100 elements)
    [0] = 1
    [1] = 0
    [2] = 1
    [3] = 1
    [4] = 1
    [5] = 1
```

Comment: Looks like the 2nd value in children[0] is 0, not 1, and you would get it via `children[0][:bitstring][1]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would get it via `children[0][:bitstring][2]`, which can be easily seen from the debugger output.

The way the debugger output is structured is as a list of `variable_name = {Class} value` where `{Class}` is the Class type of the value if it is not a primitive or a collection, in which case that part (including the braces) is left out.

When the `value` is some kind of collection, the collection type and number of elements in the collection is shown where the `value` goes, and then beginning on the next line, and indented an extra amount, each element is listed in the form `accessor = value`. If that value is also a collection, then the same thing goes again: the collection type and number of elements in the collection are shown where the `value` goes, and then beginning on the next line, and indented an extra amount. So when you look at this:

```
children = Array (101 elements)
 [0] = Hash (1 element)
  bitstring => Array (100 elements)
   key = {Symbol} bitstring
   value = Array (100 elements)
    [0] = 1
    [1] = 0
    [2] = 1
    [3] = 1
    [4] = 1
    [5] = 1
```

You should see that

- `children` is an Array
- `children[0]` is a Hash
- `children[0][:bitstring]` is an array
- `children[0][:bitstring][2]` is the third element of the `:bitstring` array and its value is the integer `1`

The way you know that the Hash key is `:bitstring` and not `"bitstring"` is that for a hash, each element is itself a collection of `key` and `value`, so you see that under the line `bitstring => Array (100 elements)` are 2 lines, one starting with `key` and one starting with `value`. The `key` is listed as `{Symbol} bitstring` which tells you it is the symbol `:bitstring`. If the key were a string, it would just say `key = "bitstring"` (note the quotation marks).

Comment: Thanks. But actually I have an algorithm in ruby which I have no idea that language, and I need to re-write in c++ so first I needed to understand ruby's syntax.